# Parse string to get a portion of the string

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string

```
"(01 Jan 2019 to 03 Jun 2020)"
```

I only want the *second date* portion, which is *dynamic*, so the day is not always
`"03 Jun 2020"` it might be `"12 Apr 2020"` for example

How do I extract a `Substring` from this particular string?

Comment: Keywords: string split, substring.

Comment: use var substrings = yourString.TrimEnd(')').Split("to"); and then DateTime.Parse(substrings[1]).

Answer (score 4):

This works for any string with the format "(date1 to date2)".

```
var dateString = "(01 Jan 2019 to 03 Jun 2020)";
var indexOfTo = dateString.IndexOf("to");
//If "to" isn't in the string
if (indexOfTo == -1)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
var result = dateString.Substring(indexOfTo + 3).Replace(")", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
var dates = input.Split(" to ", StringSplitOptions.None);
//if array dates length is not 2, you know you have an invalid format
//take appropiate measures if necessary

var firstDate = dates[0].TrimStart('(');
var secondDate = dates[1].TrimEnd(')');
```

Instructive to learn about other handy string methods that help you solve these kind of problems.

No error checking, if the string format being wrong is a possibility, you will have to make the necessary checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine *regular expressions* to obtain good *candidates* for `DateTime`s and then `TryParseExact` to parse *valid* ones into final `DateTime`:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

private static DateTime[] ExtractDates(string value, IFormatProvider provider = null) {
  return Regex
    .Matches(value, @"\b[0-9]{1,2}\s+[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[0-9]{4}\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => (DateTime.TryParseExact(
       match.Value, 
      "d MMM yyyy", 
       provider, 
       DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
       out DateTime result), result))
    .Where(tuple => tuple.Item1)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.result)
    .ToArray();
}
```

For instance:

```
DateTime[] result = ExtractDates(
  "(from 01 Jan 2019 up and including to 03 Jun 2020)", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// 3 June 2020
DateTime secondPart = result[1];
```

Comment: Do you by any chance realize that somebody asking this level of questions might find jumping into regular expressions and +15 lines of code to solve this insignificant problem just a bit overwhelming?

Comment: @InBetween: unfortunately, it's quite typical that format start slightly *changing* from sample to sample; say, `"01 Jan 2019 - 03 Jun 2020"` (no braces and `-` instead of `to`); that's why I've provided (longer) code which can cope with these possible changes

Comment: I'm not saying your solution isn't good, its probably excellent but I still find it a complete overkill considering the apparent coding skills of the person posting the question. You've got to learn to crawl first, you are proposing a dead run... Let him take baby steps: learn how to solve with " to ", then he'll stumble with ill formed formats, he'll solve that, then he'll realize that some ill formatted strings are actually valid but with slight variations, he'll then tackle that, etc. etc. Handing him a regex solution that works beautifully at his point helps him in nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<yourStringName>.substring(15)` (I think I counted right) to grab only the second date and manipulate however you please.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `")"` and `"("` with empty strings, split on `"to"`, then trim leftover white space.

```
var test = "(01 Jan 2019 to 03 Jun 2020)";

var result = test
    .Replace("(", string.Empty)
    .Replace(")", string.Empty)
    .Split("to")
    .Select(s => s.Trim());

Console.WriteLine($"First part: {result.ElementAt(0)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Second part: {result.ElementAt(1)}");
```

**Output:**

```
First part: 01 Jan 2019
Second part: 03 Jun 2020
```

Some handy string methods shown above:

- [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`String.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8)

Since I kept `result` as an [`IEnumerable<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8), I indexed it with [`Enumerable.ElementAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.8). If you want to index with `result[0]` and `result[1]`, you need to convert the result to a list or array. This can be done with [`Enumerable.ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Enumerable.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ. I also used [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) to project the strings into trimmed versions with `Trim()`.